# Jenkins: Error in Selenium Publish Report

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins, selenium-rc

I have properly configured the Seleniumhq plugin into Jenkins. I've also tried to run it in my local Jenkins and it worked. The problems I encounter are as follows:

1. suiteFile directory reads from C drive ONLY. Example, C:\TestSelenium\testSuite.html
   When I try to specify the absolute path to my test suite (workspace), I get the error

   > The suiteFile is not a file or an url ! Check your build configuration.

   Same thing happens with resultFile.
2. When I add post-build action "Publish Selenium Report," I'm getting an error because the newly created resultFile is saved into C:\TestResult\result.html and not in the workspace.